# Filter an Optional<List<Object>> in java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to Filter an `Optional<List<Object>>` in Java8. In the below example, I trying to filter the list, without collecting the full list (players). Is this possible?

```
public List<Player> getPlayers(int age, Team team) {
    Optional.ofNullable(team).map(Team::getPlayers); 
    // needs to filter players older than 20 years, without collecting it as a list.
}

class Team {

    String name;
    List<Player> players;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Player> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

    public void setPlayers(final List<Player> players) {
        this.players = players;
    }

}


class Player {

    String playerName;
    String age;

    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    public void setPlayerName(final String playerName) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(final String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: If `players` is optional, you might want to update the above code to `Optional<List<Player>> players;`, no? And as John answered, it's better to use empty list instead of null list.

Comment: are you looking for `removeIf`?

Comment: What could be worse than a signature `void getPlayers`, what do you expect this method to do?

Comment: updated the return type.

Comment: @Holger I mean the `Team` data is coming form downstream system and it can be null.

Comment: Still, lists should not be optional, as it’s enough that they can be empty. And the code becomes much simpler and clearer when it just starts with `if(team == null) return Collections.emptyList();` instead of messing around with `Optional` throughout the entire method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the updated signature of the method, what you seem to be looking for is:

```
public List<Player> getPlayers(Team team, int age) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(team).map(Team::getPlayers)
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
            .stream()
            .filter(a -> Integer.parseInt(a.getAge()) > 20)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a [bad idea to have null lists](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=59). It's better to simply have **empty** lists, but always non-null. That way you don't have to check for null all the time, you can just iterate straight away.

If you do that then you can just call `stream()` directly without any of this `Optional` business:

```
team.getPlayers().stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getAge() > 20)
```